# Parcing jSON Request data in graphql

Tags: graphql, rest-assured

Trying to do a post on a graph query in rest assured and couldn't get the query right.

Request:

```
"{query\":inventoryPositions(productRef:\"SKU_3\"){edges{node{onHand quantities{edges{node{ref quantity type}}}}}}}")
```

Response:

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "code": "400",
            "message": "Could not read document: Unexpected character ('q' (code 113)): was expecting double-quote to start field name\n 
        }
    ]
}
```

I have also tried this but not working:

```
{"query":"{inventoryPositions(productRef:\"SKU_3\"){edges{node{onHand quantities{edges{node{ref quantity type}}}}}}}"}
```

Please help.

Comment: Have you tried using POSTMAN ?

Comment: Your first request isn't valid JSON (which matches your error).  The second one looks okay at a quick glance; what error is it producing?

Answer (score 0):

basically it need 2 escape wherever u post a variable for example

"{\n"
                + "\"query\": \"{inventoryPositions(productRef: \\"SKU_3\\" locationRef: \\"locRef1\\"){edges{node{onHand quantities{edges{node{ref quantity type}}}}}}}\"\n"
                + "}"

worked for me